# Warning ilegal string offset

Tags: php, mysql

Criei uma classe com arrays para serem populados com objetos, fiz o select do banco, logo em seguida fiz um `foreach` para criar um novo objeto com cada linha do retorno do select e salvar esses objetos no array.

Porém quando tento criar um novo objeto recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Warning ilegal string offset in ['cd_anuncio'] verifiquei no banco e está igual.

Usei o `print_r` para verificar se estava havendo retorno, e verifiquei que o retorno está correto.

```
public static function getAnuncios() {

  include("conexao.php");
  $contador = 0;

  $query = "SELECT * FROM tb_anuncio";

  $result = $conexao - > query($query);

  $formatResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  print_r($formatResult);

  if (!isset($anuncios)) {

    foreach($formatResult as $anuncio) {
        $obj_anuncio = new anuncio($anuncio['cd_anuncio'],
        $anuncio['nm_titulo'],
        $anuncio['ds_anuncio'],
        $anuncio['cd_usuario'],
        $anuncio['nm_estado'],
        $anuncio['nm_cidade'],
        $anuncio['nm_bairro'],
        $anuncio['nm_categoria']);

        $anuncios[$contador] = $obj_anuncio - > getCd();
        $anuncios[$contador] = $obj_anuncio - > getNmTitulo();
        $anuncios[$contador] = $obj_anuncio - > getDsAnuncio();
        $anuncios[$contador] = $obj_anuncio - > getCdUsuario();
        $anuncios[$contador] = $obj_anuncio - > getNmEstado();
        $anuncios[$contador] = $obj_anuncio - > getNmCidade();
        $anuncios[$contador] = $obj_anuncio - > getBairro();
        $anuncios[$contador] = $obj_anuncio - > getCategoria();

        $contador++;#
        code...
    }
    die();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `mysqli_fetch_assoc` não retorna todos valores do banco, ele só retorna uma linha por vez, quando usou foreach o valor de $anuncio na verdade foram strings, pois o foreach iterou apenas uma linha baseado nos nomes das colunas, o uso correto `mysqli_fetch_assoc` seria algo como:

```
        $result = $conexao->query($query);

        if(!isset($anuncios))
        {
            while ($anuncio = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
                $obj_anuncio = new anuncio($anuncio['cd_anuncio'],$anuncio['nm_titulo'],$anuncio['ds_anuncio'],$anuncio['cd_usuario'],$anuncio['nm_estado'],$anuncio['nm_cidade'],$anuncio['nm_bairro'],$anuncio['nm_categoria']);

                $anuncios[$contador]=$obj_anuncio->getCd();
                $anuncios[$contador]=$obj_anuncio->getNmTitulo();
                $anuncios[$contador]=$obj_anuncio->getDsAnuncio();
                $anuncios[$contador]=$obj_anuncio->getCdUsuario();
                $anuncios[$contador]=$obj_anuncio->getNmEstado();
                $anuncios[$contador]=$obj_anuncio->getNmCidade();
                $anuncios[$contador]=$obj_anuncio->getBairro();
                $anuncios[$contador]=$obj_anuncio->getCategoria();

                $contador++;
                # code...
            }
            die();
        }
```

**Como é descrito na documentação do PHP**: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php#example-1936

Comment: Vlw pela resposta, implementei e rodou sem erro, só que não faço ideia de como faço para verificar se o arrey foi realmente populado vc tem alguma sugestão ?

Comment: @Reignomo como assim?

Comment: @Reignomo depois do while, antes do `die` faça isso: `if (empty($anuncios)) { echo 'Vazio'; } else { echo 'Populado'; }`

Comment: ok vlw me salvou :D